# how to identify odd 1's in a binary number

Tags: regex, tcl

how to identify odd 1's in a binary number my binary numbers is, i.e every odd bit is a 1 in binary number

```
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0   1  0 1  0  1   1  1 1  1  1  0  1  1  0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
11010101010101111110110
11101101010101100011011
11111100110101010111101
```

i want get output what bit is a odd 1 one that one i get using basic regular expression
the output each string like this

```
1 1 1  1  1 1  1  1  1
1 5 9 11 13 15 17 19 23
```

like this i want get output from each binary string

Comment: What do you mean by "odd 1's"? The number 1 is always odd.

Comment: What do you you mean by "odd 1's" ? Please clarify your question!

Comment: How about you accept some answers on your other questions first? ;)

Comment: probably the OP means odd number of 1s

Comment: Or maybe "odd ones"? As in, odd numbers, formatted as binary. Quite the mystery, this 1.

Comment: Mallikarjunarao, your edit still doesn't make much sense. Can you give *context* to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that each string represents a binary number in big-endian form (bits being numbered from zero, which refers to the last character of the string), determining if all the odd bits (i.e., bit#1, bit#3, bit#5, etc.) in the string is done by testing if the string matches this regular expression:

```
^[01]?(?:1[01])*$
```

To understand this, first let's simplify by assuming that we already know that all characters are either `0` or `1`. Given that (and ignoring non-capturing trickiness), we could have written (in expanded form):

```
^ .? (1.)* $
A BB CCCCC D <- the key
```

That's an anchored match of the whole string (`A` and `D`) which is the empty string, or any digit (`B`) or any number of a `1` followed by anything (`C`, which puts the `1` in the “odd” position) or a digit before an even number of digits with `1` in the “odd” position (`B` followed by `C`). I've just converted that basic form to the more efficient and exact representation before it by restricting the alphabet of symbols (`[01]` for `.`) and using a non-capturing parenthesis (`(?:…)` instead of `(…)`).

If you're considering the first bit to be bit #1, you need this RE instead:

```
^1?(?:[01]1)*$
```

For little-endian bit strings, you need to "reverse the RE" (or use [string reverse](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M48) on the string to be matched and use one of the other matchers). The "reversed RE" for the little-endian bit#0-first form is:

```
^(?:[01]1)*[01]?$
```

For little-endian bit#1-first:

```
^(?:1[01])*1?$
```

Remember, with all of these regular expressions it is easiest to write them in Tcl by enclosing them in `{`curly`}` braces.

---

Demonstrating:

```
foreach s {
    110010001010101111110110
    11010101010101111110110
    11101101010101100011011
    11111100110101010111101
    1110111011111010111010
} {
    set matches [regexp {^[01]?(?:1[01])*$} $s]
    puts "$s [lindex {{doesn't match} matches} $matches]"
}
```

Produces this output:

```
110010001010101111110110 doesn't match
11010101010101111110110 doesn't match
11101101010101100011011 doesn't match
11111100110101010111101 doesn't match
1110111011111010111010 matches
```

Answer (score 7):

I interpreted the question as being "finding if a given binary number contains an odd number of 1's" **. This regex will match all binary numbers with an *even* number of 1's:

```
^0*(?:10*10*)*$
```

Negate the match result to get your intended result.

** I know, probably not very likely but hey....

**Edit:** validates against the OP's input as follows:

```
110010001010101111110110 - MATCH (even number of 1's)
11010101010101111110110  - NO MATCH (odd number of 1's)
11101101010101100011011  - MATCH (even number of 1's)
11111100110101010111101  - MATCH (even number of 1's)
```

Comment: could you produce the output?

Comment: @Mallika, are you in fact just using us to tell you the oddness of your specific numbers? :)

Comment: robyaw, why are you doing `[^1]*?` instead of `0*` - since this is binary there's only two digits; no point using four characters instead instead of one, nor any benefit in using lazy/reluctant matching. Also, capturing the group is unnecessary. In summary `^0*(?:10*10*)*$` will work the same, and requires less deciphering.

Comment: @Peter Boughton: Good point, updated the answer accordingly

(To give some context, my original regex was `^[^1]*?(1[^1]*?1[^1]*?)*$`...)

Comment: I think ()'s should have been non-capturing by default... {}s aren't used for anything in a regex are they? Oh well... too late to change now :) **Edit:** Oh..yea..they are. But still !

Answer (score 3):

Let's first consider a simpler problem: using regex to match *unary* string (containing only `1`) that contains an odd number of `1`. So we want to match `1`(1), `111`(3), `11111`(5), …, but not the empty string (0), `11`(2), `1111`(4), …

To do this, you match pairs of `1`, leaving exactly one `1` unpaired. The pattern is thus ([also on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/QMQzCJpy9E)):

```
^(11)*1$
```

Now we can modify this basic pattern to accommodate the `0`. We observe that:

- `0*` can appear before the first `1`
- `0*` can appear after the last `1`
- `0*` can appear in the pairs

That is, we need to insert `0*` at these 4 points:

```
  \/  \/
^(11)*1$
/\ /\
```

Thus the pattern is ([see matches on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/7myIYxcpyp)):

```
^0*(10*10*)*10*$
```

We can do some optimizations, e.g. making the capturing group non-capturing, or even atomic, and making the `*` possessive, but this pattern as is works and will not backtrack catastrophically.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Anchors: `^`/`$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Repetition: `*`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: +1, very nicely explained answer. With Tcl's "magical" RE engine, performance is much less of a concern than for other RE implementations

Answer (score 2):

All you need to look at is the last digit.

If it's 1,the according decimal number is odd.

If it's 0, it is even.

Comment: Just in response to the notion that the "according decimal number is odd" - the even-ness of a number is a property of the number itself, not its representation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how to detect an odd binary number, you just need to look if the last digit is a 1 then it is odd.

With regex, the expression is:

```
1$
```

Or if you must match the entire string then:

```
^[10]+1$
```

But **you don't need regex** for this... in pseudo-code:

```
if right(string,1) == 1
```

This method is better than regex, because regex doesn't work backwards, so it has to go through the entire string before it gets to the end.

A `right`/`end` function can just look at the last character directly, which is of course simpler and faster.

Ok, tcl syntax for that is:

```
if {[string index $str end] eq 1}
```

**If this isn't what you're asking**:

1. Put more details into the question on exactly what you do want.
2. Mark accepted answers on some of your previous questions.

Comment: The Tcl syntax would actually be `if {[string index $str end] eq 1} ...`

Answer (score 0):

Convert to gray code and check the lsb.